# Working with Node and MySQL

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am about to start an app and according to the requirements, the logic of the app should come from the DB, the software will be a gambling app where I am using Node + Angular.

[Here is the module I am going to be using, mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql)

As you know, if I am receiving the logic from the DB, then I need to load that logic in my Node with Store Procedures (SP) . . .

My main question is, is this the proper way to work with Nodejs or is there any other thing I can propose?

**UPDATE**

Why the downvote to close? this is a legit question as I have never seen someone using Nodejs with Store Procedures, and I am searching on Google no one seems to clarify my doubt. You guys are abusing of this feature. Its just a question.

Comment: Do you want MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server? `mssql` is the latter.

Comment: You should know by now that questions need to be more specific and fit site guidelines

Comment: @charlietfl what else than this: 1 question: "is this the proper way to work with Nodejs..." 2 question: "...or is there any other thing I can propose?

Answer (score 1):

One of the most pleasant ways to work with a database in Node is to use an abstraction layer like [Sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize) so that you're not always caught up with trivial low-level concerns.

Out of the box you get a variety of tools for managing the schema through migrations, adding, altering and retrieving data with direct queries, or by building models on top of your tables to focus on business logic instead of pounding out raw queries.

Sequelize isn't the only option out there, but you certainly want something like that if you're developing anything non-trivial.

Generally stored procedures should be reserved for exceptional cases. I know some people love to build entire applications in these things, but that often leads to severe frustration for others. Consider: It's easy to run several versions of an application in parallel that all use the same schema, but running several versions of your stored procedures in parallel is often tricky if not impossible.

So I'd advise you to carefully evaluate what you absolutely need as stored procedures and what you don't. Some databases use stored procedures to extend the core database, for example adding GIS fields, which is usually pretty stable and unlikely to change in a fundamental way. Basically, only use stored procedures when the alternative is more painful and difficult.

Comment: with Sequelize I can work with SP with no problems?

Comment: Ok, now I got it, I just saw the edit you did.

Comment: Sequelize can create, alter and use stored procedures. There's nothing really special about those other than how they're declared. To Sequelize they're just another query to run.